# gluLookAt doesn't work as expected

Tags: opengl, camera

I have this function of drawing a circle:

```
void draw_circle()
{
GLint num_of_tri = 32;
GLfloat vertex[3]; 
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
const GLfloat delta_angle = 2.0*PI/float(num_of_tri);

//Draw Front tire
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);

    vertex[0] = vertex[1] = vertex[2] = 0.0;
    glVertex3fv(vertex);

    for(int i = 0; i < num_of_tri ; i++)
    {
        vertex[0] = cos(delta_angle*i) * wheelRadius; //wheelRadius is 1.0
        vertex[1] = sin(delta_angle*i) * wheelRadius;
        vertex[2] = 0.0;
        glVertex3fv(vertex);
    }
    vertex[0] = 1.0 * wheelRadius;
    vertex[1] = 0.0 * wheelRadius;
    vertex[2] = 0.0;
    glVertex3fv(vertex);
glEnd();
}
```

This is my init function

```
void init(void)
{    
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
}
```

And this is my display function

```
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    draw_circle();
    glFlush();
}
```

To my best understanding, the circle is drawn at the origin. So calling the gluLookAt function with eye values of (0,0,1.5) is not a problem right?

But whenever I'm calling gluLookAt with eye values of z, bigger than 1, the circle disappears. Why does this happen?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to setup a projection matrix for one thing. Using the default projection, your wheel is not going to fit inside your viewing volume (zNear = -1, zFar = 1).

Comment: Thanks. Is it normal that gluPerspective changes a 3d object completely? I draw a 3d car wheel, and it is completely messed up with the gluPerspective above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a call to [gluPerspective](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml).

The default `zNear` and `zFar` values of `(-1,1)` exclude your circle when you move the eye point more than one unit away.

Edit your `init` function to include:

```
gluPerspective( 45.0f, ( GLfloat )screenWidth / ( GLfloat )screenHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f );
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Is it normal that gluPerspective changes a 3d object completely?
I draw a 3d car wheel, and it is completely messed up with the gluPerspective above.

Comment: Without seeing the before/after it is hard to say what may be wrong. But I suggest reading [OpenGL Programming Guide - Chapter 3 - Projection Transforms](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name3) if you are not already familiar with perspective (and orthographic) viewing transformations. The most likely culprit though is that the aspect ratio or field of view in my provided code is affecting what you are seeing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250989/glulookat-doesnt-work-as-expected/23251330?noredirect=1#comment35581222_23251330 If you could help me here too, that would be great. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: Don't have an opportunity right now, but if the answer is still unresolved later tonight then I will look into it.